# Как можно сравнить массив и столбец из бд?

Tags: javascript, mysql, база-данных, node.js

Добрый день уважаемые форумчане. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы мой массив сравнивался с столбцом из бд, и проверять, есть ли такой элемент из массива в бд. Например:
у меня есть массив array[1,2,3], и мне нужно проверить, есть ли в моей базе данных в столбце где-то 1,2,3.
Прилагаю свой код(попытки):

```
async function checkQuery(object) {
  var numbers = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < urls[2].length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = urls[2][i];
  }
  console.log(numbers);
  sql = 'SELECT id FROM cases WHERE case_number in ("' + numbers.join('","') + '")';
  console.log(sql);
  await connection.execute(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results.length); // собственно данные
    console.log(fields); // мета-данные полей 
    for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      if(results[i] === undefined) console.log('не найдено');
      else console.log('Дело найдено!');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, какие именно данные хранятся в столбце и каков их посыл.
Если в столбце строка и вам достаточно, чтобы она включала в качестве подстроки какой-либо из элементов массива, то можно перебрать этот массив, представив в виде `case_number LIKE '%<numbers[0]>%' OR ... OR case_number LIKE '%<numbers[n]>%'`, а потом это интегрировать в квери-строку. Проценты по краям строки в sql играют роль регулярных выражений (% - любая - даже и нулевая - последовательность символов). LIKE - это оператор строкового сравнения.
Вот что для всего этого нужно:

```
async function checkQuery(object) {
  let numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < urls[2].length; i++) numbers[i] = urls[2][i];
  sql = 'SELECT id FROM cases WHERE (' + numbers.map(item=>`case_number LIKE '%${item}%'`).join(' OR ') + ')';
  let result = await connection.execute(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results.length); // собственно данные
    console.log(fields); // мета-данные полей 
    for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      if (results.length === 0) console.log('не найдено');
      else console.log('Дело найдено!');
    }
  });
}
```

Не в курсе, что вы используете для запроса, потому не знаю точно, какой ответ будет дан в случае не попадания столбца под условие. Если пустой массив - то проверить можно так, как я написал

Comment: проблема в том что, я не знаю длину массива numbers и мне надо вернуть булевое значение, true или false, в зависимости от того, нашел или не нашел

Comment: я обновил свой ответ